# What official reason is there for frogs & toads not being amphibious?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, animals

Toads were amphibious in D&D 3.5, but that doesn't seem to have carried over to Pathfinder.  Frogs and toads are amphibians in the real world (most species can breathe in both water and air indefinitely). Have the designers said why frogs, toads, and their giant variations aren't amphibious in Pathfinder?

Comment: Since “why is X designed like Y” questions are only on topic when they are asking for official statements, I have edited the question to be on-topic that way. There may be no answer, if the designers have never said anything about it! In that case, yes, Purple Monkey's advice to consult the denizens of a forum is your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Since frogs and toads cannot breathe water, they don't match the aquatic subtype description and should not be amphibious.

From the [Universal Moster Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Amphibious-Ex-) :

> #### Amphibious (Ex)
>
> **Creatures with this special quality have the aquatic subtype**, but they
>   can survive indefinitely on land.
>
> Format: amphibious; Location: SQ.

From [Creature Types and Subtypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-aquatic) :

> #### Aquatic Subtype
>
> These creatures always have swim speeds and can move in water without
>   making Swim checks. **An aquatic creature can breathe water.** It cannot
>   breathe air unless it has the amphibious special quality. Aquatic
>   creatures always treat Swim as a class skill.

Some changes made in Pathfinder are here mainly to reduce the amount of text to work with, then every creature type and subtype has a very clear and unambiguous description.

Comment: Problem being that frogs, as a general rule, seem to be able to breathe underwater just fine. The Pathfinder seems to have strangely land-based frogs/toads only!

Comment: Frogs and toads have lungs, not gills. They hold their breath underwater. Only their tadpoles have gills to breathe underwater.

Comment: They can breathe underwater through their skin, so long as the water is sufficiently oxygenated. This varies from species, with some smaller ones able to do so indefinitely. Most frogs and toads need to use their lungs for the most part, and all species will drown if their lungs are filled with water.

Comment: It would be more realistic if the partial ability to breathe in water were reflected in the rules as a special quality for the frog/toad (instead of limiting them to holding their breath), but it makes sense that they shouldn't get the full amphibious template.